# Mirror repository for codehous not picked up while maven build

Tags: maven

I am getting below error while maven build. I have added mirror repository for nexus.codehaus.org but still its going for codehaus.

Maven Build Error :-

org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:jar:1.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:pom:1.2 from/to mojo-snapshot (https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/codehaus-snapshots/): nexus.codehaus.org: Unknown host nexus.codehaus.org -> [Help 1]

Mirror repositories I have added in setting.xml:-

```
<mirror> 
    <id>no-codehaus-releases</id> 
    <name>codehaus releases</name> 
    <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url> 
    <mirrorOf>codehaus-releases,codehaus,mule-deps,codehaus.org</mirrorOf> 
</mirror> 
<mirror> 
    <id>no-codehaus-snapshots</id> 
    <name>codehaus snapshots</name> 
    <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url> 
<mirrorOf>codehaus-snaphosts</mirrorOf> 
</mirror>
```

Please let me know if i missed anything.

Comment: Codehaus repositories have been shutdown more than two years ago...all things your need are in Maven Central..which is use by Maven by default....

Comment: This means that somewhere in your pom file there is a repository definition to codehaus...You should use a `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` and redirect everything to an internal repository manager...